# HTTP Request in Java - Simple Implementation

Tags: java, eclipse

I am totally new in Java. I Have just downloaded Eclipse and the latest JDK.

Now I want to perform **REST based HTTP requests in a Java application** built specifically for this http requests, almost like a 'hello world' type application. I came across the following tutorials on how to do it, but I am not sure how to actually implement it in Eclipse as a project and as a working Java Application.

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139

---

**Now, what I did is the following:**

I took the code form the Second Link example and I saved it into a file called:

```
HttpURLConnectionExample.java
```

Here is the code inside it:

```
package com.mkyong;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

        System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
        http.sendGet();

        System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
        http.sendPost();

    }

    // HTTP GET request
    private void sendGet() throws Exception {

        String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

    // HTTP POST request
    private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        String url = "https://selfsolve.apple.com/wcResults.do";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }

}
```

and I imported it into Eclipse: **File>Open File**. So now I right-clicked on the class (HttpURLConnectionExample.java) in the right hand side 'Outline' Window and under **'Run Configurations'** I specified a 'project' for it, called **http_request**.

[image]

Now, when I right-click on the left-hand side window on 'http_requests', I go: run as>java application. It gives me the following error:

```
Launch Error: Selection does not contain a main type
```

**My question:** What **main type** do I need to specify for it? How do I actually execute the http requests as seen in the code posted above? How do I run this?

Comment: Your Java file does not seem to be inside a source folder (the eclipse compiler won't find it for compilation and the eclipse runner won't be able to run it). Make it easier: create a new Java project and put your file inside the `src` folder in a package called `com.mkyong`.

Comment: there are libraries like http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html which make this somewhat easier

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I think you're correct. The snapshot shows a project `http_requests` with no `src` folder and the file path says `..\QuickFile\Java Project\HttpURLConnectionExample.java`.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal Right, the Java file isn't part of the project. It won't get compiled and OP won't be able to run it.

Comment: Just right-click on `http_requests` project click `New > Class` to create a `HttpURLConnectionExample` class in your current project. Then paste your current code there and run as usual.

Comment: Thanks a bunch people, I really appreciate! So that is all there is to it? I first need to create a New Project, and then assign a class to it like just now? Then just run as a Java application? How would I do the output in an application window? Like an exe type application?

Comment: Thank you Sotirios Delimanolis and Ravi. Could you please put your comments into answers to score some points and help others as well?